# Increment number in XML value in CLI

Tags: xml

My file in Linux is as below:

```
<root>
        <title>Default file</title>
        <version>103</version>
        <date>Thu 20 Oct 2022</date>
</root>
```

I need to increment the version number. Any single line commands available?
The version number should change from `103` to `104` when I execute the command.

Answer (score 2):

Here we go with the well known [xmlstarlet](https://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) XML parser and [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) expression:

```
$ xmlstarlet edit -u '/root/version' -x 'text()+1' file.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <title>Default file</title>
  <version>104</version>
  <date>Thu 20 Oct 2022</date>
</root>
```

To edit *in place*:

```
xmlstarlet ed -L -u '/root/version' -x 'text()+1' file.xml
```

Note:

You can replace `text()` xpath expression with just `.`

Answer (score 2):

Use an XML-aware tool. For example, I'm the maintainer of [xsh](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh) which you can use in the following way:

```
xsh -P file.xml 'for /root/version set . .+1'
```

Answer (score 0):

With [Gizmo](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/gizmo/update.html):

```
$ java -classpath ./saxon-he-11.4.jar net.sf.saxon.Gizmo -s:file.xml
/> update /root/version with .+1
save file.xml
/> Overwrite existing file? (Y|N)
Y
Written to file.xml
/> quit
```